# Client request handler example from Effective Go leads to deadlock?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, goroutine

The [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) guide has the following example on handling client requests:

```golang
func handle(queue chan *Request) {
    for r := range queue {
        process(r)
    }
}

func Serve(clientRequests chan *Request, quit chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests)
    }
    <-quit  // Wait to be told to exit.
}
```

I ran similar code locally where client requests were just integers:

```golang
func handle(queue chan int) {
    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println("r = ", r)
    }
}

func serve(clientRequests chan int, quit chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests)
    }
    <-quit // Wait to be told to exit.
}

var serveChannel = make(chan int)
var quit = make(chan bool)
serve(serveChannel, quit)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    serveChannel <- i
}
```

However my code results in deadlock error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`.

Even though I don't understand the problem in my program conceptually I also don't understand how the original code works. I do understand that `MaxOutstanding` goroutines are spawned and they all listen to the single `clientRequests` channel. But `clientRequests` channel is only for one request so once a request comes in then all goroutines have the access to the same request. Why is this useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that calls `serve` is not supposed to run in the same goroutine as the one that fills up the channel.

In your code, `serve` launches the handler goroutines but then waits for `<-quit`. Since it's blocked, you never reach the code that populates `serveChannel`. So the workers never have anything to consume. You also never notify `quit`, leaving `serve` to wait forever.

The first step is to send data to `serveChannel` in a separate goroutine. eg:

```golang
func handle(queue chan int) {
    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println("r = ", r)
    }
}

func serve(clientRequests chan int, quit chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests)
    }
    <-quit // Wait to be told to exit.
}

func populateRequests(serveChannel chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        serveChannel <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    var serveChannel = make(chan int)
    var quit = make(chan bool)
    go populateRequests(serveChannel)
    serve(serveChannel, quit)
}
```

We now have all requests being handled as desired.

However, you'll still encounter `all goroutines are asleep` once processing is done. This is because `serve` ends up waiting for the `quit` signal but there's nothing to send it.

In a normal program, `quit` would be populated after catching a signal or some `shutdown` request. Since we don't have anything, we'll just have it shut down after three seconds, also in a separate goroutine.

```golang
func handle(queue chan int) {
    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println("r = ", r)
    }
}

func serve(clientRequests chan int, quit chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests)
    }
    <-quit // Wait to be told to exit.
}

func populateRequests(serveChannel chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        serveChannel <- i
    }
}

func quitAfter(quit chan bool, duration time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(duration)
    quit <- true
}

func main() {
    var serveChannel = make(chan int)
    var quit = make(chan bool)
    go populateRequests(serveChannel)
    go quitAfter(quit, 3*time.Second)
    serve(serveChannel, quit)
}
```

As for your last question: the multiple handlers won't be seeing the same requests. The moment one handler receives a value from the channel, that value is removed from it. The next handler will receive the next value. Think of a channel as a First-In-First-Out queue that is safe for concurrent use.

You can find the last iteration of the code on [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nwf9UwkekwC).